# Group duplicate files

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, file

Here is my source code which group duplicate files together, written in Python 2.7. Any advice on smarter ideas to group duplicate files together more efficient, it will be great. Any general advice on code bugs and code style are also appreciated.

**Problem statement:**

I am given a list of files e.g. `["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt", "4.txt", "5.txt", "6.txt"]`. I want to group all files which have the exact same content. Suppose in this example, file `"1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"` are the same, file `"4.txt", "5.txt", "6.txt"` have common header, but `"4.txt", "6.txt"` are exactly the same whole content. Then, the output should be two groups `"1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"` and `"4.txt", "6.txt"`.

**My major idea:**

1. To avoid reading full content for each file, I generate a hash code for a file header (in my example, I define the file header to be the first two bytes of a file)
2. If more than 2 (>=2) files have the same header, I will read the full content and see if they are the exact same whole content

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
def group_duplicate_files(files):
    hash_buf = defaultdict(list)
    for f in files:
        hash_buf[hash_header(f)].append(f)
    result = []
    for file_list in hash_buf.values():
        if len(file_list) < 2:
            continue
        for file_pair in itertools.combinations(file_list,2):
            if compare_full_content(file_pair[0], file_pair[1]):
                n = set()
                n.add(file_pair[0])
                n.add(file_pair[1])
                found = False
                # try to merge with existing set
                for i,r in enumerate(result):
                    if len(r.intersection(n)) > 0:
                        found = True
                        break
                if found:
                    n = n.union(result[i])
                    result.remove(result[i])
                    result.append(n)
                else:
                    result.append(n)
    return result

def hash_header(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    header = f.read(10)
    return hash(header)
def compare_full_content(filename1, filename2):
    file1 = open(filename1, 'r')
    file2 = open(filename2, 'r')
    content1 = file1.read()
    content2 = file2.read()
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(content1) and j < len(content2):
        if content1[i] != content2[j]:
            return False
        i += 1
        j += 1
    if i < len(content1):
        return False
    if j < len(content2):
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = ["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt", "4.txt", "5.txt", "6.txt"]
    print group_duplicate_files(files)
```

Comment: In the *Major idea* part, you write the contradictory statement "If more than 2 (>=2) files have the same header". I assume it is meant to be "if at least 2 (>=2) ...".

Comment: @Graipher, yes, this is what I mean, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your algorithm is something like \$\mathcal{O}(n!)\$, because you compare all possible pairs of files. It is possible to do this in \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

You just have to iterate over the files and order them into a hashmap (i.e. dictionary) based on their header hash. Then, resolve the possible conflicts of two files with the same header, but different content, which takes \$\mathcal{O}(k)\$, where \$k\$ is the number of files with the same header. So in the worst case (all files have the same header), this algorithm is \$\mathcal{O}(2n)\$.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys


def hash_content(file_name, length=-1):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return hash(f.read(length))


def group_by_header(*file_names):
    file_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for file_name in file_names:
        file_groups[hash_content(file_name, length=10)].append(file_name)
    return file_groups


def group_by_content(*file_names):
    file_groups = group_by_header(*file_names)
    for file_names in file_groups.values():
        if len(file_names) > 1:
            while file_names:
                file_name = file_names.pop()
                file_groups[hash_content(file_name)].append(file_name)
    return filter(None, file_groups.values())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_names = sys.argv[1:]
    print group_by_content(*file_names)
```

This code has two caveats:

1. It assumes `hash` is collision-free (a fair assumption). We could pass the string content directly as a key and let python do the hashing. Then we would also get a [strategy for the rare case that two strings have the same hash without being equal](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/02/how-hash-collisions-are-resolved-in.html). But this way we avoid storing the possibly large file-contents as strings.
2. This uses the fact that `dict.values()` returns a list and not an iterator, so we can modify the dictionary in the loop here. This breaks in Python 3.x, but you specifically tagged this as Python 2.7. You can remedy this by introducing a new dictionary:

```
def group_by_content(*file_names):
    header_hashs = group_by_header(*file_names)
    content_hashs = defaultdict(list)
    for hash_, file_names in header_hashs.items():
        if len(file_names) > 1:
            while len(file_names):
                file_name = file_names.pop()
                content_hashs[hash_content(file_name)].append(file_name)
        else:
            content_hashs[hash_] = file_names
    return (val for val in content_hashs.values() if val)
```

Comment: Nice answer Graipher. Why do you think my algorithm time complexity is `O(n!)`? I think my code has the same idea as your overall logic (I totally agree your code detailed implementation is more cleaner than mine)?

Comment: BTW, is there a way we can even skip calculating hashing of header?

Comment: @LinMa Because you do `for file_pair in itertools.combinations(file_list,2)` when comparing with fullcontent.

Comment: @LinMa you could do `file_groups[open(file_name).read(10)].append(file_name)`, but as I said this would be big in memory if you also did it for the fulltext...

Comment: Nice catch, Graipher! And do you think when we find potential duplicate content at the first step, shall we calculate hashing or we can have a way to compare faster by just byte to byte compare?

Comment: @LinMa When comparing coe by content you have the advantage that you can stop as soon as you find a difference. On the other hand, you have to compare all combinations of pairs, which could possible be a lot of file reads and also a large number of comparisons. (Imagine `n` long files with the same header, all different only by the last character. You would have to read all files completely before knowing if they are different).

Comment: @LinMa After thinking some more, I realized that `combinations` with length 2 will only generate `binom(n+1, 2) = 0.5*(n^2 + n)` comparisons. But this is still O(n^2).

Comment: @LinMa I think my function will not be significantly slower, unless most of your files differ by the 11th byte and you don't have very many. But some testing would be needed for this.

Comment: BTW, Graipher, start a new post and we can continue to discuss and also learn if any others have smarter ideas. :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158844/group-duplicate-files-part-2